# Making movieclips react realistically when hittest

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I tried to create the basic of soccer game , all i have managed to create is the Player Movements:
http://www.fastswf.com/1d9dCxE prees X to kick

FLA:
http://www55.zippyshare.com/v/24746890/file.html

The Code (add the MC first):

```
var isRight:Boolean=false
var isLeft:Boolean=false
var isUp:Boolean=false
var isDown:Boolean=false
var xspeed:Number=0
var yspeed:Number=0
var maxspeed:Number=5
var accel:Number=0.3

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, downKey);
function downKey(event:KeyboardEvent){
 if(event.keyCode==39){
 isRight=true}
 if(event.keyCode==37){
 isLeft=true}
 if(event.keyCode==38){
 isUp=true}
 if(event.keyCode==40){
 isDown=true}
 if(event.keyCode==88){maxspeed=5;}
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, upKey);
function upKey(event:KeyboardEvent){
 if(event.keyCode==39){
 isRight=false}
 if(event.keyCode==37){
 isLeft=false}
 if(event.keyCode==38){
 isUp=false}
 if(event.keyCode==40){
 isDown=false}
  if(event.keyCode==88){maxspeed=6;}
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
function loop(Event){
// if right is pressed and speed didnt hit the limit, increase speed
if(isRight==true && xspeed<maxspeed){xspeed+=2}
// if left is pressed and speed didnt hit the limit, increase speed (the other way)
if(isLeft==true && xspeed>-maxspeed){xspeed-=2}
// if speed is more than 0, decrease
if(xspeed>0){xspeed-=accel}
// if speed is less than 0, increase
if(xspeed<0){xspeed+=accel}

// just like x, but with y
if(isDown==true && yspeed<maxspeed){yspeed+=2}
if(isUp==true && yspeed>-maxspeed){yspeed-=2}
if(yspeed>0){yspeed-=accel}
if(yspeed<0){yspeed+=accel}

// apply speed to movieclip
mc.x+=xspeed
mc.y+=yspeed

// managing the walls
if(mc.x<0 && xspeed<0){mc.x=0}
if(mc.x>470 && xspeed>0){mc.x=470}
if(mc.y<0 && yspeed<0){mc.y=0}
if(mc.y>370 && yspeed>0){mc.y=370}

}
```

As you see, the code needs improvements.

I strive to create a game like this one:
haxball.com

```
Notes:
after you have navigated to haxball.com:
Choose any nickname
Click on "Create Room"
Click on "Create"
Click on "Red Team"
Click on "Start"
Move Around, Tuch The White Ball
```

As you see there is: `Red Team` + `Blue Team` + `A White Ball`.

In my project i only have a player that can move around :( ,
And my current mission is to change it,
So what i need to do first is to find a way to make the ball react properly to my player hittest (physics,mathematics and many others) i've never did anything like this before,
 
so i'am here to ask a few things:
1.someone can give me the right direction (demos/examples/explanations (I prefer not to))?
2.someone here have ever done something like this before? (Optional: if you did,  your code/Suggestions will help me to finish this project(for sure)).
Note: Remember that i'm not a pro, But i can understand code better than explanations, And I can also learn the subject better if it's a code.

**NOTE: Feel free to use the FLA file.**
Another Note:
I know that here nobody is asking for code (This is my personal preference),But it is very important to me so I asked anyway, If you have something to say about it Keep it to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are huge nuber of examples on the internet, just first few pages found for search query: "as3 ball collision physics":

http://www.freeactionscript.com/tag/collision-reaction/

http://flashcove.net/452/elastic-collision-detection-and-resolution-between-entities-in-flash-as3/

http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/when-worlds-collide-simulating-circle-circle-collisions--gamedev-769

Also you can use some as3 physics engines like:

http://napephys.com/samples.html#

http://www.box2dflash.org/